# Unable to align heading to the left side

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a demo page here [DemoPage](https://ibb.co/mw4DqK)
and i am trying to create one like this. This page will be getting dynamic data from backend as it is made editable. So what i have created here is this page [CreatedPage](https://ibb.co/dgiOqK). The heading above each paragraphs needs to be on the left side while the paragraph and picture will be reversed with each iteration. I am unable to fix the heading on left side above each paragraph. I have an alignment property according to which with each iteration every row is being reversed and for that i have made use of class binding. Also right now the paragraph is not inline with picture .This is getting very difficult for me now. How can i make the heading stay on the left side while ensuring that paragraph and picture will stay inline and will keep reversing on every iteration?  Please check the code on this stackblitz site [PageCreated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list-oqpkbw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just don't want to nest the heading? Try this:

```
<h1>App Comp</h1>
<section>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; even as isLeft" >
    <h4>{{ item.heading }}</h4>
    <div class="card-item" [class.paraRight]="isLeft">
      <div class="image-container">
      <img [src]="item.image">
      </div>
      <div class="desc-container">
        <p>{{ item.paragraph }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i think this is right but the paragraphs are center aligned now instead of staying left aligned. Like the one in pictures

Comment: Sorry, I don't totally understand the requirements. But I think you should try the css property "text-align" to get what you want. Like text-align: right or text-align: left

Comment: yes it worked now if you can please tell how i can keep just a little space between the image and paragraph then that would be awesome since you have solved all my problem

Comment: haha sure. add this css: img { margin: 0 10px } and that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
    <h1>App Comp</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of data;even as isLeft">
      <h4>{{ item.heading }}</h4>      
    <section>
      <div class="card-item"  [class.paraRight]="isLeft">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img [src]="item.image">
    </div>
    <div class="desc-container">
      <p>{{ item.paragraph }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</section>
</div>
```

updated the stack biltz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list-hqjqh5

and to give space between image and para

```
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding:8px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vaibhav :)